# Which season/episode is the scene where Walter White enters the CT scanner/radiation therapy machine

Tags: breaking-bad, identify-this-episode

I remember a scene in *Breaking Bad* where Walter White is covered in a plastic sheet and going into a machine for his lung cancer. It's a radiotherapy machine I believe, but for the life of me I cant find the scene when I'm watching and fast forwarding through the episodes.  I feel like it was Season 1, or possibly Season 2.

Does anyone remember what I'm talking about?

I'm doing a project on radiation therapy and if I could get to this clip it would be amazing.

Comment: Do you mean the MRI? Cause it appears at least twice, in the [pilot](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/File:1x01_-_Scanning_Walt.jpg) and in [5x08](http://www.tv.com/news/breaking-bad-gliding-over-all-mid-season-finale-review-system-of-a-frown-29468/) (scroll to the end).

Comment: @Walt I'll watch those episodes you just listed tonight, but im not sure if its those based on the screenshots you have there.  The one im thinking of is that hes covered in a saran wrap type material thats used as part of the radiation therapy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [Gray Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_Matter_%28Breaking_Bad%29), season 1 episode 5, when Walt finally agrees to undergo the treatment. He's scanned about 5 minutes before the end of the episode. It's a machine that uses what looks like a vacuum-sealed clear plastic sheet and green radiation rays. Here's a picture:

[image]